# Why 'ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list' is occurring if x is there?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, spyder, valueerror

This is a code that opens a table .csv and read line per line to save data in two variables, saved in a list. Moreover, I want to filter some data of sheet (.csv) because I don't need it, and I'm filtering applying what is below, there is, x.remove(i) and y.remove(i) but they both are in error as i reported in the title. What should i do? What mistake am i doing?

```
g=float(9.8)

x=[]
y=[]

dados = open('dados123.csv').readlines() #trocar para o nome_do_arquivo após testes de diagnóstico



def adiciona_dados():
    for i in range (len(dados)):
        if i !=0:  
            linha = dados[i].split(";")
            x.append(float(linha[0]))
            y.append(float(linha[1])*g)
        else:
            print('erro1')

len(x)
len(y)
adiciona_dados()



for i in y:  
    if y[i] < 30:

        x.remove(i)
        y.remove(i)              
    else:
        print('nada')

len(x)
len(y)
```

Comment: the data from the sheet are addition by the first and unique function that the code has: adiciona_dados(), and this is working because when I code len(x) or len(y) there are data saved in the list.

Comment: You have *different numbers* in your two lists.  Trying to remove the same number from both lists would work only by coincidence.  (And note that removing items from a list as you're iterating over it will result in items being skipped - iterate over a copy of the list, instead).

Comment: better filter it when you append() - so you will not have to remove it.

Comment: BTW: you can do `for line in dados[1:]` instead of `for i in range(len(dados))`  and `if i !=0:` and `dados[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Orignal code:

```
for i in y:  
    if y[i] < 30:

        x.remove(i)
        y.remove(i)              
    else:
        print('nada')
```

Modified code version1:

```
for i in y:  
    if i < 30:

        x.remove(i)
        y.remove(i)              
    else:
        print('nada')
```

Otherwise,Python list method remove() searches for the given element in the list and removes the first matching element. But if two adjacent elements are repeated, it will remove first one and the second will be reserved.

Modified code version2 for repeated num:

```
for i in y:
    if i < 30:
        while x.count(i)>0:
            x.remove(i)
        while y.count(i)>0:
            y.remove(i)
    else:
        print("nada")
```

Comment: " But if two adjacent elements are repeated, due to python automatic memory management,it will remove first one and the second will be reserved" What? That behavior has nothing to do with automatic memory management. That is due to a *logical error* of trying to remove from a list while iterating given the behavior of a Python list iterator, or in the case that you've shown, the same error will occur due to removing by index but not accounting for how the underlying list and the indices are changed when you change the size of the list...

Comment: Dear daichaoyang, thank you for your answer and for edits on my code. But the problem still there, with another strange thing. I ran your code and this can't filter in just one time, I have to rerun several times the specific part that you coded to make the results converge to my data objective, which is filter data of cells minor than 30.0 in the list. Moreover, python shows me whenever I ran the code that 
  File "C:/Users/Renan/Documents/Python Scripts/teste_de_filtro.py", line 41, in <module>
    if y[i] < 30:

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: To better show you, here is the specific part of your code that i rerun several times and the data that python showed to me:

Comment: len(y)
Out[2]: 1280

for i in range(len(y)):  
    if y[i] < 30:

        x.remove(x[i])
        y.remove(y[i])

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-8f76b43bdc9e>", line 2, in <module>
    if y[i] < 30:

IndexError: list index out of range




len(y)
Out[4]: 651  and it occurred more nine times until i get the results that i wanted, which is:

Comment: en(y)
Out[24]: 23

y
Out[25]: 
[33.66594,
 60.069100000000006,
 120.44102000000001,
 266.30030000000005,
 456.42128,
 611.49746,
 707.30226,
 759.0864400000002,
 785.67384,
 779.49494,
 747.0981,
 701.4438200000001,
 647.2076800000001,
 594.56992,
 540.03488,
 466.04782000000006,
 371.61894,
 272.4743,
 189.01652000000004,
 124.05526,
 76.57132,
 45.93848,
 30.734760000000005]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. We didn't have an example of your `dadoos123.csv` file. But we can try to understand what your were trying to do. Here's my solution for your problem:

```
import csv

g = 9.80

with open('dados123.csv', newline='') as dados_file:
    dados_reader = csv.reader(dados_file, delimiter=';')
    print('erro1')
    all_linha = list(dados_reader)
    x = [float(current_linha[0]) for current_linha in all_linha[1:] if float(current_linha[0]) >= 30]
    y = [float(current_linha[1]) * g for current_linha in all_linha[1:] if float(current_linha[0]) >= 30]

how_many_nada = (len(all_linha) - 1) - len(x)     # Could also been (len(all_linha) - 1) - len(y). No difference
for current_nada in range(how_many_nada):
    print('nada')
```

Is that what you were trying to do?

Comment: Dear EvensF, thank you for your answer! The problem still there, because when I tried to use your code, the ValueError was: too many values to unpack (expected 2). In .csv file I have more than 2.6k of values in each column, then, each list will save this number of values to filter.

Comment: You should better explain your problem because there was no way for me to guess what data looked like. There's less chance someone will be willing to help you otherwise. When you ask a question try to give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I changed my answer would that be better like that?

Comment: I'm noob in community, and not a native speaker, then sorry for any troubles. I'm going to try your code.